# Even sized list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I've been trying to write a predicate which would evaluate the size of a list to be even or not and this has to be done without computing the length of the list or any arithmetic operations. It's supposedly easier than computing the length but I'm having trouble thinking of how to do it without that. I'm guessing a sort of recursive technique but if anyone is able to help it would be great.

Comment: You are interested in lists of even length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is too late to answer your question, but hopefully this will help:

To find list has odd length:

```
oddlength([_]).
oddlength([_,_|R]) :- oddlength(R),!.
```

To find list has even length:

```
evenlength([]).
evenlength([_,_|R]) :- evenlength(R),!.
```

Comment: Given that you only care about the odd/even list length, use anonymous variables as placeholders except for the list tail for the recursive call.

Comment: I posted this answer, but removed it since it's a homework question. In general, don't give people doing their homework the entire solution. They will copy-paste.

Comment: @keyser Sure, I'm new here, Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Your solution produces two answers for `evenlength(L)` Why two? Also, the second term in oddlenth/2 is invalid Prolog text. Most systems ignore it...

Comment: @false have you checked my edition that I used ! which is "cut" symbol and means no backtracking, make sure your are using the latest version with !, when you use ! you don't get multiple answers

Comment: @AMIRHOSSEIN: `oddlength([X,Y,Z]),!.` is invalid - apart from the fact that no cut is needed in this predicate - in fact the cut makes it slower.

Comment: @false Please feel free to improve the answer, I just edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you want recursion. The base cases would be the smallest odd/even lists you can have, and then all you need is to figure out how to construct the recursive call so that it will boil down to the base case. You could start out by imagining a list of length 3 that's supposed to return true for "oddList". If it's not the base case, what's the next logical step? How does an odd list differ from an even one?

Comment: There are no functions in Prolog.

Answer (score 4):

**Preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity)**! Simply proceed like this:

```
evenlength([]).             % smallest list with even length is [] (length=0)
evenlength([_|Xs]) :-
   oddlength(Xs).

oddlength([_|Xs]) :-        % smallest list with odd length is [_] (length=1)
   evenlength(Xs).
```

Some simple ground queries for `evenlength/1` and `oddlength/1`:

```
?- evenlength([]).
true.
?- oddlength([]).
false.

?- evenlength([1]).
false.
?- oddlength([1]).
true.

?- evenlength([1,2]).
true.    
?- oddlength([1,2]).
false.

?- evenlength([1,2,3]).
false.    
?- oddlength([1,2,3]).
true.
```

Note that these predicates can not only *test* candidate lists, but also *generate* them:

```
?- evenlength(Xs).
  Xs = []
; Xs = [_A,_B]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F]
...

?- oddlength(Xs).
  Xs = [_A]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G]
...
```

Comment: Why `...sized/1`? Size often means term size which includes all arguments.

Comment: And why not `evenlength/2`?

Answer (score 2):

Using [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) `foldl/4` and [Prolog lambdas](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord) all we need to do is:

```
evenlength(Xs) :-
   foldl(\_^E^O^(O is \E),Xs,1,1).   % each item in `Xs` flips the "evenness flag"
```

Sample uses:

```
?- evenlength([]).
true.

?- evenlength([_]).
false.

?- evenlength([_,_]).
true.

?- evenlength([_,_,_]).
false.

?- evenlength([_,_,_,_]).
true.
```

Let's not forget about the most general query!

```
?- evenlength(Xs).
  Xs = []
; Xs = [_A,_B]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F] 
...
```